# JSON Call from view to controller and show JSON object data in view in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written code in an ASP.NET Core 6 controller and calling this from view. This code gives response to my view but I don't know how to parse the data in view.

Previously I was using `JsonrequestBehaviour.Allowget` which is now deprecated in .NET 6. Please help me for better appraoch of json call which can return any dynamic object.

Here is my controller code:

```
public IActionResult GetAccountLevelAndCode(Int32 GroupAccountID, Int32 Companyid)
{
    string AccountLevels = ""; string Returnerror; string ReturnBranches;
    DataTable AL = new GetDataClass().GetAccountNoAndAndLevels(GroupAccountID, Companyid, out Returnerror);
    //a = (GLChartOFAccountModel)AL.Rows[0].ConvertDataRowToObject(a);
    string Sql = @"select cab.BranchID from GLChartOFAccount ca inner join GLChartOfAccountBranchDetail cab on ca.GLCAID=cab.GLCAID where cab.GLCAID=" + GroupAccountID;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = StaticClass.SelectAll(Sql).Tables[0];

    AccountLevels = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AL);
    ReturnBranches = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

    Returnerror = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Returnerror);

    return Json(new { AccountLevels, ReturnBranches, Returnerror });
}
```

Following is my view call and response allocation:

```
 function GetAccountNoandLevel() {
    var DATA={"GroupAccountID" : $('#isParent').val(), Companyid : @Model.CompanyID }
    var execCode = true;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GLChartOFAccount/GetAccountLevelAndCode",
        data: DATA,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            try {
                var c = JSON.parse(data.AccountLevels)
                var b = JSON.parse(data.ReturnBranches)
                var er = JSON.parse(data.Returnerror)

                if (b.length>0) {

                    $("#BrachIDs option").each(function () {
                        var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                        this.disabled = true;
                    });
                    var dataarray = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                        dataarray += b[i]["BranchID"] + ',';
                    }
                    dataarray = dataarray.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
                    var data = dataarray.split(",");
                    $("#BrachIDs").val(data);
                    $("#BrachIDs").change();
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#BrachIDs option").filter("[value='" + data[i] + "']").attr('disabled', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#BrachIDs option").each(function () {
                        var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                        this.disabled = false;
                    });
                    $("#BrachIDs option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                }

                if (ShowErrorOK(er)) {
                    $('#GLCode').val('');
                }else{
                    RowToFillValues(c)
                }

            } catch (e) {
                //console.log(e + " GetAccountNoandLevel "); document.getElementById("DisplayErrorMessage").innerText = e.message; $('#btnTriggerMessage').click(); execCode = false; return false;
                console.log(e + " GetAccountNoandLevel "); console.log(e.message)
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //console.log(err.responseText); document.getElementById("DisplayErrorMessage").innerText = "AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err.statusText + " " + err.status) + " GetAccountNoandLevel::Unable To Get Details"; $('#btnTriggerMessage').click(); execCode = false; return false;
            console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err.statusText + " " + err.status) + " GetAccountNoandLevel::Unable To Get Details")
        }
    });

    if (execCode) {
        
    }
}
```

The response data is showing `undefined`...

Comment: You have to create a partial view, or show us the view you have now.

Comment: This is My view and on Change of parentID tag value I am Call the Above Mentioned Jquery Function

Comment: Can't post the code of complete view as it is too lengthy I am just calling a simple ajax call to controller and getting the response back on view. Everything is working fine but the responce which is returned from server side can't parse to json as we used to parse by using JSON.parse.
This may be because in .Net 6 jsonrequestbehviour.allowget is not availble so is there any other way that we can get responce through Ajax calls??

Comment: Allowget doesn't do anything, forget about it.

Comment: There is no need of the partial view here.

Comment: Ok but with allowget I was able to use JSON.Parse in old MVC project which was developed in .Net framework. But Now this is giving me Undefined responce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need serialize and parse manually, it will be done automaticaly

```
return new JsonResult(new { AccountLevels=AL, ReturnBranches=dt, Returnerror= Returnerror });
```

and ajax

```
var c = data.AccountLevels;
var b = data.ReturnBranches;
var er = data.Returnerror;
```